# How to Skip Existing Checkstyle Errors/Warnings in Existing Code

Tags: checkstyle

I am new to Checkstyle, and wants to implement checkstyle standard checks on existing code, i wants to skip the existing Errors/Warnings and exclude the respective Files those are having Error/Warning for concern check. so if any developer leave any new Error/Warning, it should be reported.
can anyone please suggest me, how can i achive file level and checks specific exclusion in checkstyle, a simple example will make grate help to me.

Comment: Are you trying to find the delta between two checkstyle runs in order to find out which findings are "new"? Or are you simply trying to figure out how to exclude certain files from certain checks?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, so we solved it with Jenkins+Checkstyle plugin for it.
You can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14764804/checkstyle-and-jenkins-check-modified-added-lines-in-svn-commit)